# Read string from one file, grep the first occurrence in another file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm reading a string from file, appliances_list.txt.

appliances_list.txt contains

```
fridge
dryer
ironbox
microwave
```

The file I'm reading is myappliances.txt. Content is

```
I have a fridge
I have another fridge
I have a refridgerator
I have a microwave
I have ironbox at home
I have another microwave
I have a hairdryer
```

I'm using

```
grep -o -m1 -f appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt
```

Output is

`fridge`

My desired output is, first occurrence of each string (exact match)

```
fridge
microwave
ironbox
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { strings[$0]; ++numStrings; next }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i in strings) {
            print $i
            delete strings[$i]
            if (--numStrings == 0) {
                exit
            }
            break
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt
fridge
microwave
ironbox
```

That will be very efficient since it will remove each found string from the list of strings as it's found so there's fewer comparisons necessary on every line and when there's no more strings in the list will exit the program so it doesn't waste time reading the remaining lines of the 2nd file.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Ed Morton . Thanks. The solution worked for the example I had given. But did not work for my actual file. I think the reason is, in myappliances.txt appliances are inside a tag. <Appliance>fridge</Appliance>, for example. Can you suggest a solution for that? I have updated the question.

Comment: My advice is to put this question back the way it was, accept an answer that solves that question, and post a new 3rd attempt at your question and please really THINK about it this time before posting so we don't have to go through yet another series of iterations to get to what it is you really want to do. None of the answer currently posted are the best approach for what you're now describing.

Comment: Sure. Shall do.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]; next }{ 
              gsub(/<\/?[^<>]+>/,"",$0); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
              if ($i in a && !a[$i]){ a[$i]++; print $i; break } 
    }' appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt
```

- `a[$0];` - capturing pattern words from `appliances_list.txt`
- `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through fields/words of the line from `myappliances.txt`

The output:

```
fridge
microwave
ironbox
```

Comment: @Nandu, see my update for your new `myappliances.txt` file

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as following. This would work very efficiently (considering your filesize is 2GB)

```
while read -r appliance; do grep -m1 -ow $appliance myappliances.txt;done<appliances_list.txt
```

`-w`: for exact word match

Output:

```
fridge
ironbox
microwave
```

Explanation:
Firstly,in your code, the `-m1` is causing to stop matching once first match is found and it stops reading the file causing the program to exit.

What you have to do is iterate over file1 and for each word in it grep over file2 and use your logic.

Other solution is :

Use **head -1** along with grep to stop searching after first match is found.

```
while read -r appliance; do grep -ow $appliance myappliances.txt | head -1; done<appliances_list.txt
```

Comment: @Nandu: This will work for your updated file as well. Cheers !

Comment: That will be immensely slow since it's reading the whole of the 2nd file once for every word in the first file. It has other fundamental shell issue too (missing `IFS=` and unquoted variable) but that might not cause the usual problems given the samples posted.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for pointing Ed. What do you think of performance improvements if I delete the matched lines with sed for each iteration ?

Comment: It'd help a little but that'd get complicated since you're reading the file you'd be sed-ing and it'd still be orders of magnitude slower than 1 call to awk reading both files once each. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for a discussion of some of the issues.

Comment: @EdMorton: That's a good read. I'll come back here tmrw after giving it some time. Thanks for your suggestions and help Ed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `-m1` and pipe to `sort -u`:

`grep -owf appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt | sort -u`

`sort -u` will sort and then unique the lines.  If that sorting is undesired, you might have to use something like awk. perl, or python.

Note that to get only `dryer` and not `hairdryer` you need `grep -w`, so the suggestion above has -o**w**.

Comment: `uniq` only remotes duplicate consecutive lines, so you might have to sort the output first

Comment: @Tom... right.  `sort -u` replaced as the suggestion

Comment: I think there are two issues here (I'm not sure). grep might search the whole file (myapplicances.txt). I dont want that to happen, since my actual file is huge (2 GB). I want it to move to second string, once the match for first is found.

Comment: @stevesilva, uniq didn't work for me. It printed all. sort -u worked. But like I mentioned in previous comment, I dont want to search the whole file, and then sort.

Comment: @Nandu - ahh.  That makes this more interesting. It will have to search until the *last* match at least, and if there are any unmatched strings, the whole file.  Which is to say, if you expect them all to match... do you also *want* the order?