# Read strings from a file, find the first match of that string in another file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm reading a string from file, appliances_list.txt.

appliances_list.txt contains

```
fridge
dryer
ironbox
microwave
```

The file I'm reading is myappliances.txt. Content is

```
I have a <Appliance>fridge</Appliance>
I have another <Appliance>fridge</Appliance>
I have a <Appliance>refridgerator</Appliance>
I have a <Appliance>microwave</Appliance>
I have <Appliance>ironbox</Appliance> at home
I have another <Appliance>microwave</Appliance>
I have a <Appliance>hairdryer</Appliance>
```

I'm using

```
grep -o -m1 -f appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt
```

Output is

`fridge`

My desired output is, first occurrence of each string (exact match)

```
fridge
microwave
ironbox
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? 
Please note that myappliances.txt is a sample file. My real file is 2GB in size. So need an optimized solution. Something like, when the first match for String1 is found, stop searching for String1 and move to String2.

This is NOT a duplicate of [Read string from one file, grep the first occurrence in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985910/read-string-from-one-file-grep-the-first-occurrence-in-another-file) . myappliances.txt pattern is different in both cases.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985910/read-string-from-one-file-grep-the-first-occurrence-in-another-file

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate, it's a followup (though the OP should have said that in the question and explained what's different about this one).

Comment: You do not want to scan myampliances.txt more than once. The last hit from appliances._list.txt can be nere the last line. You can use your current `grep` without m1 and pipe it htrough `sort -u` or you can write an `awk` program that will store the data from one file in an array first.  
You should start with a good definition of a match, will `fridge` match `refridgerator`? Can we compare the list with `sed -r 's/.*>([^<]*).*/\1/' | sort -u` ?

Comment: @Walter A , can't use grep and pipe to sort, since myappliances.txt  is 2GB  size in real life. When the first string1 match is found, immediately has to move to String2.
It should be an exact match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read string from one file, grep the first occurrence in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985910/read-string-from-one-file-grep-the-first-occurrence-in-another-file)

Comment: Not a duplicate. See Ed Morton's comment above,.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="</?Appliance>" }
NR==FNR { strings[$0]; ++numStrings; next }
$2 in strings {
    print $2
    delete strings[$2]
    if (--numStrings == 0) {
        exit
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk appliances_list.txt myappliances.txt
fridge
microwave
ironbox
```

Comment: this worked for small file. When used with 2 GB myappliances.txt file, it was taking ever, even to print the first match. Is it breaking after first match?

Comment: idk what `Is it breaking after first match?` means but it should complete in seconds given what you'd told us about your input files since it's just doing a hash lookup of the relevant text from myappliances.txt in an ever decreasing hash table built from the so-far-unseen contents of appliances_list.txt and then it exits if/when the last string from appliances_list.txt has been found. You're not running it in a shell loop or something are you?

Comment: I'm not running in shell loop. When myappliances.txt is 2GB in size, it was taking ever to print, even the fist string "fridge". So I was assuming, after it found the first match of "fridge" in myappliances.txt, it was still looking for "fridge" in myappliances.txt .

Comment: I took around 300MB of my file, myappliances.txt and ran the test. It took around 1 min to complete. There was no output.
Is it because of file size? My appliances_list.txt has around 1000 entries.

Comment: No, as you can see once it finds each string the first time it deletes it from the array (hash table) and so will not look for it again. Also as you can see it works for the sample you posted so it'll work for any larger sample that follows that same format. 1000 entries in one file and 300MB in another is not a problem. It sounds like your real files just do not look like the sample you posted so all I can suggest is adding some debugging `print` statements to the code to trace what's being added to the array and the `$2` values later.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#.*#/\\<&\\>/{s/.*/&/;G;/^([^\\n]*)\\n.*\\1/!P;h}#' list |
sed -rf - -e 'd' file
```

Create a sed script from the list file and run it against the text file.

The sed script stores the matches in the hold space and only prints the match when it is unique.

Comment: since the real life file, myappliances.txt is 2 GB in size, I want the program to move to String2, when it finds first occurrence of String1. myappliances.txt shouldn't be scanned for next occurrence of String1, after the first one is found.